# The 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, oledbconnection

I've tried everything from targeting x86, downloading AccessDatabaseEngine, Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable, going to Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Web Projects and unchecking 'Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects'. I uninstalled every Office app I had. I downloaded Office 2013 32-bit so I have Access 2013, Visual Studio Express 2015 for Web.

I have Test.accdb database so I have to connect trough OleDbConnection.

Here is the part of my code that is relevant. I've got something after I open the connection but it doesn't matter because it doesn't even get there:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace FirstTest
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\FirstTest\App_Data\Test.accdb;Persist Security Info=True;";

            connection.Open();

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;


        }
    }
}
```

After I build the project I get an error on 'connection.Open()'.

The weird thing is if I go to Server Explorer, right click on my DB and I click on Refresh it puts something green over it. And every time I build it gets a red thing.

I have W10 64 bits. This is a test to get a job interview, the task is really easy but I can't test what I've done so far because I can't connect to the database.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have `Provider=` twice, should only appear once.

Comment: I can't believe it. Now it works!! I want to cut my @#$%. I'm pretty sure it wasn't just this, but now I can connect!!!